# Delete array of structs from an array of structs Swift

Tags: swift

I have an array of structs that looks like this:

```
struct minStruct {

var namn:String?
var imag:UIImage?
var rea:String?
var comp:String?
```

}

```
var structArr = [minStruct]()
```

If I would like to remove a specific struct from that array, I could simply do this:

```
var oneStruct = minStruct(namn: "Name", imag: UIImage(named: "Image"), rea: "Something", comp: "Something")

if structArr.filter({$0.namn == oneStruct!.namn}).count > 0 {

structArr = structArr.filter({$0.namn != oneStruct!.namn})
```

}

However, what I would like to do is to remove an array of structs from structArr. Something like this:

```
structArr = [minStruct(namn: "Name", imag: UIImage(named: "Image"), rea: "Something", comp: "Something"), minStruct(namn: "secondName", imag: UIImage(named: "secondImage"), rea: "Something2", comp: "Something2"), minStruct(namn: "thirdName", imag: UIImage(named: "thirdImage"), rea: "Something3", comp: "Something3")]

var arrToDelete = [minStruct(namn: "Name", imag: UIImage(named: "Image"), rea: "Something", comp: "Something"), minStruct(namn: "secondName", imag: UIImage(named: "secondImage"), rea: "Something2", comp: "Something2")]
```

So what I want to do is to delete all the items that are inside of arrToDelete from arrStruct. In this example, arrToDelete contains two of the three structs that structArr contains. I want to delete these two structs and keep the one struct that arrToDelete did not contain. I hope that I was clear enough!

Comment: Are you new in swift ?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that, sorry for being unclear and if there is something you want me to explain tell me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Hashable

So we have struct. First of all let's make it `Hashable`

```
struct Element: Hashable {
    var name: String?
    var image: UIImage?
    var rea: String?
    var comp: String?
    var hashValue: Int { return name?.hashValue ?? image?.hashValue ?? rea.hashValue ?? comp.hashValue ?? 0 }
}

func ==(left:Element, right:Element) -> Bool {
    return left.name == right.name && left.image == right.image && left.rea == right.rea && left.comp == right.comp
}
```

### Data

Next we have these 2 arrays

```
let elms : [Element] = [
    Element(name:"a", image:nil, rea:nil, comp:nil),
    Element(name:"b", image:nil, rea:nil, comp:nil),
    Element(name:"c", image:nil, rea:nil, comp:nil)
]

let shouldBeRemoved: [Element] = [
    Element(name:"b", image:nil, rea:nil, comp:nil),
    Element(name:"c", image:nil, rea:nil, comp:nil)
]
```

### Solution #1

If you **DO NOT** care about the original **sorting** you can use

```
let filtered = Array(Set(elms).subtract(shouldBeRemoved))
```

### Solution #2

If you **DO** care about the original **sorting**

```
let shouldBeRemovedSet = Set(shouldBeRemoved)
let filtered = elms.filter { !shouldBeRemovedSet.contains($0) }
```

> **Why didn't I just write this?**
>
> ```
> let filtered = elms.filter { !shouldBeRemoved.contains($0) }
> ```
>
> The line above is a correct solution. However invoking `contains` on
>   `Array` is generally slower (usually n/2 checks need to be performed)
>   than invoking it on a `Set` (usually a single check).

Comment: It only gives me an error message when I try to make it Equatable; "type minStruct does not conform to protocol Equatable". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @MarkusJohansson: You must define the `==` function. Look again at my first block of code

Comment: Note that the `Hashable` protocol requires `Equatable`, so you only have to conform to `Hashable` ;)

Comment: @originaluser2: absolutely true. Thank you! I updated my answer.

Comment: Good solution in general, but the hash function could be improved. Right now you can have two structs whose `namn` is the same but other values are different hash to equal.

Comment: @rickster: Totally true. I provided a very dumb logic for the hash value :D

Answer (score 0):

Structs for some reason aren't really allowed to be compared using Boolean logic, thus it's hard to even search an array of Structs for an item or the item's index.  So for instance, if you wanted to search an array of Structs for a specific struct and then delete it:

First, you'd need to go to your struct file and give it a protocol which allows the struct to be used in `boolean` logic, so...

```
struct Persons: Equatable {
      struct properties...
       struct init....
      }
```

Then you could search within the array using array methods such as...

```
firstIndex(of: theStructYourLookingFor)
lastIndex(of: _)
```

or any other boolean-related array methods.

This could be newish as of Swift 4.0 and greater-- April 2019